# Deleting a file and a folder in a FTP folder, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

So basically I'd like to know how to do so.

I have no idea how to do so, a macro that'd delete a file or a folder from a ftp folder that's defined in windows (a network folder)

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do this, but the easiest would probably be with `Kill`.

**Delete one file**

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim myPath as String

    myPath = "\\server\Folder\File"

    If Dir(myPath) <> "" Then Kill myPath
End Sub
```

**Delete multiple files of the same type**

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim myPath as String

    myPath = "\\server\Folder\*.xls"

    If Dir(myPath) <> "" Then Kill myPath
End Sub
```

**Delete all files in a folder**

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim myPath as String

    myPath = "\\server\Folder\*.*"

    If Dir(myPath) <> "" Then Kill myPath
End Sub
```

**Delete Entire Folder**

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim myPath as String

    myPath = "\\server\Folder\*.*"
    myFolder = "\\server\Folder\"

    If Dir(myPath) <> "" Then 
        Kill myPath
        RmDir myFolder 'For RmDir to work, the folder has to be empty
    End If
End Sub
```

There are many more ways to do this, I'm just showing an example with `Kill`. You could use FSOs to do all of this as well.

**Important:** You cannot undo deleting an item like this. This permanently deletes the file. (It doesn't go to the recycle bin, you can't bring files back to life that you've killed.)

Comment: I dont get how to use it as a ftp...
If my server is some ip and i put it in the "server" section its not working.
to access this dir from windows i'd do ftp://server and it'd work in windows.
no method is working in vba.
how would i set mypath to direct to a ftp folder?

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, just wanted to say that the kill command is for files and not for folders.
I'd like to get more alternatives.

Comment: @matanjustme So, the thing is, you didn't really provide me with any code to work off of, so I provided you with a method to deleting a file, and updated to show you how to delete a folder as well. As far as writing code to navigate to a specific file or FTP folder, that would be a different question.....

Comment: Let me rephrase that last part: if you want to know how to write VBA code to access and modify FTP folders and files, make a new question stating that. That is the structure of StackOverflow, and as such would help more people who search for those specific questions.

Comment: The thing is you've mentioned the ftp info as server, and I was wondering what the input would be.
I have the ftp folder in My Computer, if I enter its IP as "server" in the given example, it gives an error.
Anything I've tried gives an error.
Can you give me an example of how to work with a network drive? And please an example that you've tried, because either kill or dir functions aren't working as far as I've tried.

Comment: Also my question is specifically for FTP folders... not for Windows folders, as I've already mentioned in both my title and description.

Comment: Like I said... this works for FTP files and folders.... If you want to know how to access your FTP files, you should make a new question stating such............. There's so many ways you can do this... Here's an example using my code: `Kill "//user/folder/file.file"`. Do you not have direct access and permissions to the folder?

Comment: I didn't understood what you meant by your rephrasing at first, but after this comment I did.

I got it to work thanks to you.

Best regards, I'm very thankful and i hope this thread will help many others facing the same problem as I did.